# Static type checking in Vuejs source code

Tags: javascript

I got pretty confused after reading the following [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org/) helper snippet:

```
export function isPrimitive (value: any): boolean %checks {
  return (
    typeof value === 'string' ||
    typeof value === 'number' ||
    typeof value === 'boolean'
  )
}
```

Where did the static type checking come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [flow type annotations](https://github.com/facebook/flow).